# About burn a disk on win 10

Tags: iso-image, dvd-burning

I want to burn a iso file on a DVD but I accidently put winrar as defaul app. So can any one say me how can I burn the iso files on the disks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click (ISO) > Open with > Select the Image Burner

You may have to select 'Choose Another Application' and then select it.